# Elixir in 2018 Annual Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

It has been present in the survey in previous years and seems to have grown in popularity over the last year. Just wondering what happened to it this year? Was it combined with Erlang? Were there not enough responses?

Comment: This is not a duplicate any more than claiming two questions about how to reverse a list in two different answers are the same. In particular with Elixir, it's odd that previous years included Elixir yet this year it didn't and as a result I know many Elixir developers voted for Erlang on many questions as a proxy.